# How can I print a "Hello World" string in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

I cannot figure out to print a string in the middle of step. The syntax is constrained to Given/Then syntax. I need to print a string. How can I do this?

Comment: what about doc string in cucumber?did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it from your step definition.

Answer (score 0):

in the step definition just specify the string to print

ie:

When /^I do something cool$/ do
  puts "cool"
end

so when the step:
When I do something cool

is executed "cool" will be printed out to the console